# Is Swift's handling of CVarArg for String buggy?

Tags: swift, interop, variadic-functions

While writing a Swift wrapper for a C wrapper of a C++ library, I've stumbled on some weird bugs regarding Swift's `CVarArg`. The C wrapper I already have uses variadic functions which I converted to functions using `va_list` as an argument so they could be imported (since Swift cannot import C variadic functions). When passing arguments to such a function, once bridged to Swift, it uses the private `_cVarArgEncoding` property of types conforming to `CVarArg` to "encode" the values which are then sent as a pointer to the C function. It seems however that this encoding is faulty for Swift `String`s.

To demonstrate, I've created the following package:

#### Package.swift

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.2

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "CVarArgTest",
    products: [
        .executable(
            name: "CVarArgTest",
            targets: ["CVarArgTest"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "CLib"),
        .target(
            name: "CVarArgTest",
            dependencies: ["CLib"])
    ]
)
```

### CLib

#### CTest.h

```c
#ifndef CTest_h
#define CTest_h

#include <stdio.h>

/// Prints out the strings provided in args
/// @param num The number of strings in `args`
/// @param args A `va_list` of strings
void test_va_arg_str(int num, va_list args);

/// Prints out the integers provided in args
/// @param num The number of integers in `args`
/// @param args A `va_list` of integers
void test_va_arg_int(int num, va_list args);

/// Just prints the string
/// @param str The string
void test_str_print(const char * str);

#endif /* CTest_h */
```

#### CTest.c

```c
#include "CTest.h"
#include <stdarg.h>

void test_va_arg_str(int num, va_list args)
{
    printf("Printing %i strings...\n", num);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        const char * str = va_arg(args, const char *);
        puts(str);
    }
}

void test_va_arg_int(int num, va_list args)
{
    printf("Printing %i integers...\n", num);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        int foo = va_arg(args, int);
        printf("%i\n", foo);
    }
}

void test_str_print(const char * str)
{
    puts(str);
}
```

#### main.swift

```swift
import Foundation
import CLib

// The literal String is perfectly bridged to the CChar pointer expected by the function
test_str_print("Hello, World!")

// Prints the integers as expected
let argsInt: [CVarArg] = [123, 456, 789]
withVaList(argsInt) { listPtr in
    test_va_arg_int(Int32(argsInt.count), listPtr)
}

// ERROR: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
let argsStr: [CVarArg] = ["Test", "Testing", "The test"]
withVaList(argsStr) { listPtr in
    test_va_arg_str(Int32(argsStr.count), listPtr)
}
```

The package is available [here](https://github.com/thebluepotato/CVarArgTest) as well.

As commented in the code above, printing a `String` via C or a `va_list` containing `Int`s works as expected, but when converted to `const char *`, there's an exception (`EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)`).

So, in short: did I mess up the C side of it or is Swift doing something wrong here? I've tested this in Xcode 11.5 and 12.0b2. If it's a bug, I'll be happy to report it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one's a bit tricky: your string is actually being bridged to an Objective-C `NSString *` rather than a C `char *`:

```
(lldb) p str
(const char *) $0 = 0x3cbe9f4c5d32b745 ""
(lldb) p (id)str
(NSTaggedPointerString *) $1 = 0x3cbe9f4c5d32b745 @"Test"
```

<sup>(If you're wondering why it's an `NSTaggedPointerString` rather than just an `NSString`, [this article](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-07-31-tagged-pointer-strings.html) is a great read -- in short, the string is short enough to be stored directly in the bytes of the pointer variable rather than in an object on the heap.</sup>

Looking at [the source code for `withVaList`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/62eab29ed91c905511e14ce5aa423c5a3b28631a/stdlib/public/core/VarArgs.swift#L145), we see that a type's `va_list` representation is determined by its implementation of the `_cVarArgEncoding` property of the [`CVarArg`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/62eab29ed91c905511e14ce5aa423c5a3b28631a/stdlib/public/core/VarArgs.swift#L42) protocol. The standard library has some implementations of this protocol for [some basic integer and pointer types](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/62eab29ed91c905511e14ce5aa423c5a3b28631a/stdlib/public/core/VarArgs.swift#L218), but there's nothing for `String` here. So who's converting our string to an `NSString`?

Searching around the Swift repo on GitHub, we find that [Foundation is the culprit](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/9ee3c0eab1b19cc89ba3296ffcb10c348329b42b/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/Foundation.swift#L238):

```
//===----------------------------------------------------------------------===//
// CVarArg for bridged types
//===----------------------------------------------------------------------===//
extension CVarArg where Self: _ObjectiveCBridgeable {
  /// Default implementation for bridgeable types.
  public var _cVarArgEncoding: [Int] {
    let object = self._bridgeToObjectiveC()
    _autorelease(object)
    return _encodeBitsAsWords(object)
  }
}
```

In plain English: any object which can be bridged to Objective-C is encoded as a vararg by converting to an Objective-C object and encoding a pointer to that object. C varargs are not type-safe, so your `test_va_arg_str` just assumes it's a `char*` and passes it to `puts`, which crashes.

So is this a bug? I don't think so -- I suppose this behavior is probably intentional for compatibility with functions like [`NSLog`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1395275-nslog) that are more commonly used with Objective-C objects than C ones. However, it's certainly a surprising pitfall, and it's probably one of the reasons why Swift doesn't like to let you call C variadic functions.

---

You'll want to work around this by manually converting your strings to C-strings. This can get a bit ugly if you have an array of strings that you want to convert without making unnecessary copies, but here's a function that should be able to do it.

```
extension Collection where Element == String {
    /// Converts an array of strings to an array of C strings, without copying.
    func withCStrings<R>(_ body: ([UnsafePointer<CChar>]) throws -> R) rethrows -> R {
        return try withCStrings(head: [], body: body)
    }
    
    // Recursively call withCString on each of the strings.
    private func withCStrings<R>(head: [UnsafePointer<CChar>],
                                 body: ([UnsafePointer<CChar>]) throws -> R) rethrows -> R {
        if let next = self.first {
            // Get a C string, add it to the result array, and recurse on the remainder of the collection
            return try next.withCString { cString in
                var head = head
                head.append(cString)
                return try dropFirst().withCStrings(head: head, body: body)
            }
        } else {
            // Base case: no more strings; call the body closure with the array we've built
            return try body(head)
        }
    }
}

func withVaListOfCStrings<R>(_ args: [String], body: (CVaListPointer) -> R) -> R {
    return args.withCStrings { cStrings in
        withVaList(cStrings, body)
    }
}

let argsStr: [String] = ["Test", "Testing", "The test"]
withVaListOfCStrings(argsStr) { listPtr in
    test_va_arg_str(Int32(argsStr.count), listPtr)
}

// Output:
// Printing 3 strings...
// Test
// Testing
// The test
```

Comment: "a bit tricky" is quite an understatement haha! SO in short, when using `va_list` in Swift, a `String` has to be converted manually to a cString pointer, which is the handled correctly through it's own `_cVarArgEncoding`. Although I understand the need for compatibility with `NSLog`, the extension for bridged types is very old compared to recent developments in Swift and I'd expect the default behaviour here to be then one you implemented. I'll have to do some additional tricks because my arguments are of mixed types...

Comment: If you feel like it, I suggest putting your answer here as well: https://forums.swift.org/t/using-va-list-in-c-function-with-a-swift-string-raises-exc-bad-access/38424